# R: How to subset dataframe over columns from 2 different dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

How to subset dataframe over columns from 2 different dataframe using R code?

Here is the dummy code:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(b = rep(LETTERS[1:4],2), c = c("B", "A", "A", "E", "G", "H", "K", "L"))

#   b c
# 1 A B
# 2 B A
# 3 C A
# 4 D E
# 5 A G
# 6 B H
# 7 C K
# 8 D L


data2 <- data.frame(d = c("A", "B", ""), e = c("E", "", "C"))
#    d e
#1   A E
#2   B  
#3     C


subset <- subset(data, data$b %in%  c(data2$d, data2$e))

#   b c
# 1 A B
# 2 B A
# 3 C A
# 5 A G
# 6 B H
# 7 C K
```

As you can see, i can use subset() function to overlap "data" to "data2". But what if i have large  number of columns in "data2"? is there a way to simplify this code? If possible tidyverse approach is preferred.

I tried to use below code, but its not working.

```
subset_try <- subset(data, data$b %in%  data2[,c(1:2)])
#[1] b c
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are lots of columns, `unlist` into a `vector` and `subset`

```
subset(data, b %in% unlist(data2))
```

If we want only a subset of columns, then select the subset of columns and `unlist` - Note that `data2[, c(1, 2)]` is still a data.frame with two columns and not a vector, thus when we do

```
> data$b %in% data2
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

It has to do with the `table` argument with `%in%`.  According to `?"%in%"`

> x %in% table

> table  - **vector** or NULL: the values to be matched against. Long vectors are not supported.

Therefore, we may want to convert to vector

```
> data$b %in% unlist(data2)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
> subset(data, b %in% unlist(data2[1:2]))
```

---

For the tidyverse, it is just replacing the `subset` with `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
filter(data, b %in% unlist(data2[1:2]))
```